# Rolling Four Dice Probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

If I roll $4$ distinguishable six-sided dice, what is my probability of rolling $2$ even and $2$ odd numbers?

What I did:

$\binom{4}{2}$ Because out of the four rolls two you want to be even, and this will be same for the odd. Then you would multiply this by $\frac{1}{2}^4$ because that is the probability of each die.

Thus, the total is: $$\binom{4}{2}\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^4$$

My question is, is this approach and answer correct? Struggling and looking for feedback.

Comment: There is no need to square as you did - think about it as picking $2$ dice that will be odd - then the rest of the dice will have to be even.

Comment: Ahhh, I see! Correct me if I am wrong, but $\binom{4}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^8$, no? Because the other two have to be odd in this context?

Comment: Close - note that the probability that two dice (given you've picked them already) will be even and two will be odd is just $(1/2)^2*(1/2)^2 = (1/2)^?$

Comment: Thank you! So we are rolling four dice and each has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ and we choose 2 to be our even! Makes enough sense. So this would be accounting getting 2 even and 2 odd right?

Comment: As you can tell, combinatorics is not my strong suit at the moment.

Comment: Yes - exactly. and no worries - these things took me a while as well! Practice makes perfect (and I am in no respects near perfect!)